# gcloud compute config-ssh produces no Host entries

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to use [gcloud compute config-ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/config-ssh) to set up Host entries in my $HOME/.ssh/config. The command runs with no errors but when I look in my $HOME/.ssh/config it has just added a comment block with no Host entries, like this:

```
# Google Compute Engine Section
#
# The following has been auto-generated by "gcloud compute config-ssh"
# to make accessing your Google Compute Engine virtual machines easier.
#
# To remove this blob, run:
#
#   gcloud compute config-ssh --remove
#
# You can also manually remove this blob by deleting everything from
# here until the comment that contains the string "End of Google Compute
# Engine Section".
#
# You should not hand-edit this section, unless you are deleting it.
#
# End of Google Compute Engine Section
```

When I run `gcloud compute instances list` I see all my instances, so I know I have gcloud set up properly.

Comment: Apologies for the perhaps obvious question: are you able to ssh into these instances directly? Either using `gcloud compute ssh ...` or `ssh` directly? I tried this (as I was unaware that this `gcloud` command exists) and it worked correctly for me.

Comment: Yep, I can ssh to my instances.

Comment: Hmmm. Is there anything noteworthy in `gcloud compute config-ssh --log-http`?

Comment: Which version of Cloud SDK do you use? Try to update/reinstall it to the latest one `279.0.0`. I've checked on my Linux machine and command `gcloud compute config-ssh` worked for me. I found created file `~/.ssh/config` with my instance description `Host instance-1.europe-west3-a.test-prj` and so on. Also, I was able to use command `ssh user@instance-1.europe-west3-a.test-prj` to connect to it.